# how to save file on server (Ldap3 authentication using python)

Tags: python, authentication, post, server, ldap3

I've already got a successed  authentication using this code:

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL

    # define the server
    s = Server('ldap://***.***.**.201:389', get_info=ALL)
    # define the connection
    c = Connection(s, user='***', password='***')
    c.bind()
```

Like our admin said - this is the server for authentication
and i'd like to save a file on server ***.***.**.204 which uses that authentication.
So how can I save file from my folder to the server ***.***.**.204 in folder ***.***.**.204:\1_СТМ using authentication from server ***.***.**.201:389????

Comment: do you want to save a file (that is present on your local system) in server?

Comment: Yes. I'd like to save a file on server ***.***.**.204 but it is worth mention that authentication is on ***.***.**.201. I dont know whether it is usefull information or not)

Comment: I think I got your question....No, I am on another server. But on my Windows mashine I am able to map a network drive (that server) and save a file directly. And so then using python commands i can enter a disk like on my logical disk. 
But i want to know how to do this not in such a way